# Pointers in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am exploring a concept of **Pointers** in C and C++. I have already read so many articles about it but still I have got some doubts. Looking forward that anyone of you can clear them.

So Here's my questions:

Declared Single Dimensional array like this:

```
int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Now I am printing below values:

```
printf("array--->%u", array);       // Output: 3199709072
printf("&array--->%u", &array);     // Output: 3199709072
printf("*array--->%d", *array);     // Output: 1
printf("*&array--->%d", *&array);   // Output: 3199709072
```

First three output are same as what I expected but I dont understand the fourth one.

**Why is it printing an address of first element of array??**

I am using `*&array` expression that means I am explicitly specifying that I want value at `&array` address but still it prints address of first element.

Any ideas??

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour for some calls. `printf` expects an integer and you pass pointers. And for the last one: Why do you expect an array to be a pointer, although it clearly is called "array" and not "pointer"?

Comment: Aside: please use the format specifier `%p` for a pointer, and cast the pointer argument as `(void*)...`

Comment: @Olaf Well I am not using this code with native c or c++ compiler but with Android NDK. I am using %d for sake of simplicity bcz it gives me something like 3199709072 and  not 0xbeb7af90.

Comment: @Vikalp I hope my answer will help you! thanks

Comment: And how does that change your code invoking UB?

Comment: @Olaf: This code is defined on android because the integer happens to be the right size.

Comment: @Joshua: Same size does not mean "defined"! You want to learn what "undefined behaviour" implies. Read the standard and don't spread such nonsense.

Comment: @Olaf: The C standard doesn't define this, but the POSIX platform spec does.

Comment: @Joshua: So POSIX defines `int` having the same bit-width as any pointer? I wounder how POSIX64 works which uses I32LP64.

Comment: @Olaf: That's funny. My copy says you can't do that and lists the following code as defined: realloc(); void function() { ... realloc(&p, newsize); } which can only possibly work if sizeof(int) == sizeof(void **). In addition, android is always 32 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When unary `*` and unary `&` comes together they nullify each others effect. `*&array` is equivalent to `array`. Since arrays decays to pointer to its first element when passed as an argument to a function, `array` will give address of the first element of the array `array`.

Looking it another way, the expression `*&array` will be parsed as `(* (&array) )`; retrieve the address of array `array` and then dereference it. Since `&array` is an address of an array, dereferencing it will give back the array itself, but as per the rule the dereferenced array will decay to pointer to its first element and it will make the expression `*&array` equivalent to `array`.

---

**NOTE:** Use `%p` specifier to print address. Like

```
printf("array--->%p", (void *)array);
```

Otherwise, using wrong specifier will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: A comment would be appreciated for the reason for downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Use the %p instead instead to get the pointer address in memory. Your code will generate undefined behaviors. Simply use the following example.

```
printf("%p \n",pointer);
//where pointer is array in your case
```

That should do.